# page does not redirect to an error page in django

Tags: python, django

The page doesn't redirect to an error page if the value is less than the current bid and doesn't update the bid if the user add another one.

views.py:

```
def add_bid(request, id):
    username = request.user.username # get username
    item = Auction_listings.objects.get(pk=id)
   
    try:
        bid_value = float(Bids.objects.get(auction=id).bid_value)
    except:
        bid_value = float(item.product_price)

    if request.method == "POST":
        new_bid_value = float(request.POST.get("bid"))

        if new_bid_value > bid_value:
            new_bid = Bids(auction=item, username=username, bid_value=bid_value)
            new_bid.save()
        else:
            return render(request, "auctions/error.html", {
                "error": "your bid is lower than the current bid..."
            })
```

models.py:

```
class Auction_listings(models.Model):
    product_image = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    product_description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    product_category = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="others")
    product_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    is_closed = models.BooleanField(default=False)    
    winner = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, verbose_name='posted date')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.product_title}"


class Bids(models.Model):
    auction = models.ForeignKey(Auction_listings, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    bid_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.bid_value} by {self.username} in {self.auction}"
```

thank you in advanced!

Comment: Could you please clarify how/what request is sent? For example, is it really a POST? The wrong method would certainly be the simplest explanation for the observed behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I used python lists for collecting previous bid history so you can find the current price easily by implementing max(bidlist).

This is my solution to this problem:

In views.py:

```
    if request.method == "POST":
    listing = Listings.objects.filter(title=title).first()
    bids = Bid.objects.filter(list=listing)
    bidslist = []
    userlist = []
    for p in bids:  #for every bid object in the list
        bid = p.bid
        bidslist.append(bid)
        u = p.user
        userlist.append(u)
    if bidslist != []:
        currentprice = max(bidslist)
    else:
        currentprice = listing.startingbid
    form = BidForm(request.POST)
    user = request.user


    if form.is_valid():
       last_bid = form.cleaned_data['bid']
      // print(last_bid)
       if currentprice >= last_bid:
           messages.add_message(request,messages.WARNING,"Your bid must be greater than current price")
           return HttpResponseRedirect('/' + title)
```

Maybe helpful to use Django form instead manually doing HTML forms. It looks like you have problem on getting correct data from the form?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the way you are accessing the `bid_value` in your views.py.

```
bid_value = float(Bids.objects.get(auction=id).bid_value)
```

will raise a **MultipleObjectsReturned** Exception when number of bids is more than one. So you will end up with the except statement with `bid_value = original_price`

So, change the code to this.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
try:
    bid_value = float(Bids.objects.filter(auction=id).latest('bid_value').bid_value)
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    bid_value = float(item.product_price)
```

Here what it does is, it tries to get all the bids of current auction and latest gets the object with highest bid_value. Then we collect the bid_value from that object. :D